# Work out missing row in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, record

I have a table that will eventually get a row missing through deletion of records.

How could I check for that missing row in that table then fill this missing row in PHP.

I guess its using looping however I just cant work out the correct loop to use

Cheers

Comment: You need to clarify your question.

Comment: Why do you need to fill the missing row?

Comment: post your code so we can look, if i had a nickel for every time i have said this....

Comment: If you're referring to a missing value in the auto_increment column, those are intended to be unique, not necessarily sequential (due to deletions). They should not be relied upon to produce sequentially numbered records when `SELECT`ing

Comment: The question can't be clearer.. I need to find the missing row in the sequential AUTO_INCREMENT ID rows and fill that in. Example:

Row Data
1
2
3

5

The script would detect row 4 is missing and then the SQL query would be INSERT INT... WHERE ID="4"

I can't work out how to find out which is the first missing row however.

Comment: @Brad Morris _The question can't be clearer_ Nowhere does your question mention `AUTO_INCREMENT` id columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find a missing item in a sequence is to compare count(*) and max(id).
It should give you an idea of how many are missing, then start including ranges that your checking as in a binary search.

Alternate way is just iterate over the rows ordered by id, and trigger your insert when the sequence jumps.

```
$lastId = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    if ($lastId + 1 != $row['id']) {
        fillInRows($lastId + 1, $row['id'] -1);
    }
    $lastId = $row['id'];
}

function fillInRows($min, $max)
{
   for ($i = $min; $i <= $max; $i++) {
       // exercise left for the reader
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

-- Apparently the question isnt as vague as the moderators thought -.-